# How to reliably detect if NSParagraphStyle thinks it is (part of) a list?

Tags: swift, uikit, nsattributedstring

I have some truly cursed code which detects whether an `NSParagraphStyle` instance has non-empty "lists", by inspecting the `style.description` string:

```swift
attributedString.enumerateAttribute(
    .paragraphStyle, 
    in: fullLength,
    options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired
) { style, range, _ in
    guard let style = style as? NSParagraphStyle else { return }
    if let maybeList = style.description
            .components(separatedBy: "Lists (\n")
            .dropFirst().first,
        !maybeList.starts(with: ")") {
   // we have (part of) a list-item! ... but I feel dirty
}
```

This works for description strings like this one:

```
Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 36, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (
    11L,
    36N
), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (
    "NSTextList 0x6000014408d0 format <{disc}>"
), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0 PresentationIntents (
) ListIntentOrdinal 0 CodeBlockIntentLanguageHint '(null)'
```

But it's not what I would call "robust" `:-)` The docs do mention a [`textLists`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsparagraphstyle/1534193-textlists) property, but it's only in AppKit (macOS), while I'm building for UIKit (iOS). It does rather look like it's *there* though, under the covers, judging by the description string. So: can I get to it "legitimately"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to create lists with a `(NS)AttributedString` at the time of writing. To make lists of your own, you'll need to use tricks like `headIndent` as [this article](https://medium.com/@at_underscore/create-lists-with-attributedstring-in-ios-15-cc6df2297251) shows.

However, `NSParagraphStyle` still responds to the `textLists` selector (at least for now), even though it doesn't expose `textLists` as a property as in AppKit.

Therefore, you could technically do:

```
extension NSParagraphStyle {
    var containsLists: Bool {
        let sel: Selector = "textLists"
        guard self.responds(to: sel) else { return false }
        guard let list = self.perform(sel).takeUnretainedValue() as? [Any] else { return false }
        return !list.isEmpty
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this will get your app rejected from the App Store or not.